# Install git package on different path with composer

Tags: php, wordpress, git, composer-php

I'm trying to install a repository from git in a custom path using composer because I'm using Bedrock for WordPress.

In my `composer.json` I have this block of code:

```
// ...
repositories: [{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
        "version": "1.0.2",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        }
    }
}]
// ...
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"]
    }
}
```

The `composer.json` of my repository has the following content:

```
{
    "name": "juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "description": "A extended version of ACF Google Maps plugin with some more functionality.",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-name": "advanced-custom-fields-google-map-extended"
    }
}
```

I followed the instruction of the composer to install it on a custom path but didn't work. It installs on `vendor`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing `composer.lock` I realized that for my custom repositories are inserted there like this:

```
// ...
{
    "name": "juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
        "reference": "master"
    },
    "type": "library" // Notice here! Type is set to "library"
} // ...
```

Type is set to `library`, so I added `"type": "wordpress-plugin"` on my `composer.json`, like that:

```
{ // ...
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin", // Here is where I changed.
    "source": {
      "url": "https://github.com/juniorgarcia/acf-gme",
      "type": "git",
      "reference": "master"
    }
  }
} // ...
```

This worked. I also changed the `installer-name` adding this information like:

```
// ... on my composer.json
"extra": {
    "installer-name": "advanced-custom-fields-google-maps-extended" // This also worked
 }
```

**Even with this working, I wonder why composer does not read my packages' `composer.json` files which already have informations like `type` and `type`.** I appreciate if somebody could explain me.